# JS RegExp for -> A followed by 2 digits

Tags: javascript

I have multiple direction lines such as the following:

`Continue straight to stay on < b>Honiton Rd< /b>/< b>A30< /b><div style="font-size:0.9em">Continue to follow A30`

Within these I need to see if theres any road that starts with an A and its remainder is in digits.

So in the following I would be looking to get A30 from the above string.

`Continue straight onto < b>A303< /b>`

They always start with the bold tag, so I assume the RegExp needs to do something along the lines of find bold tag, check first character for a, check rest for ints.

How can I represent this set of rules in a regular expression in javascript?

**EDIT**

**LIST OF EXAMPLES**

Continue straight to stay on < b>Honiton Rd< /b>/< b>A30< /b>Continue to follow A30  ===> A30

Continue straight onto < b>A303< /b> ===> A303

Turn right onto < b>A4067< /b> ===> A4067

Turn left onto < b>Dover Rd< /b>/< b>M3< /b> ===> null

Comment: Could you provide list of sample such as :
<b>A303</b> ==> A30 ||
<b>A23</b> ==> A23 || 
<b>A1</b> ==> A1 ?

Comment: Added a list of examples

Comment: You can use `/A\d{2,}/g` for the purpose.

Comment: I confirm, what vibhor1997a prupose.

Comment: Thank you people!